# Convert list elements to generalised dictionary element in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as shown below. There is a column containing elements as a list of items, the number of items being different in each row. I would like to convert the list element to a dictionary element with Boolean value as shown in the output. What is the fastest way to do it?

DataFrame:

```
Index  Value
0      [Cat,Dog,Rat]
1      [Cat,Dog,Horse]
2      [Cat,Dog,Horse,Rat]
3      [Cat,Horse,Rat]
4      [Dog,Horse,Rat]
```

Expected Output:

```
Index  Value
0      {'Cat':'Yes','Dog':'Yes','Horse':'No','Rat':'Yes'}
1      {'Cat':'Yes','Dog':'Yes','Horse':'Yes','Rat':'No'}
2      {'Cat':'Yes','Dog':'No','Horse':'Yes','Rat':'Yes'}
4      {'Cat':'No','Dog':'Yes','Horse':'Yes','Rat':'Yes'}
```

Comment: why do you call it *binary value* ? Post how was the dataframe declared?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The dataframe is generated by a mongo query from the DB. It has the value as a list. And, i mentioned binary because each of them has to be shown as 'Yes' or 'No' based on if they are present in the list or not

Comment: You mean `boolean value` then.

Comment: Yes. I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I create a variable with all possible keys called `keys` . Then

```
df.Value.apply(lambda x: dict((key,"Yes") if key in x else (key,"No") for key in keys))
```

**Example output**:

```
>>> data = {'Value': [['Cat', 'Dog', 'Horse', 'Rat'], ['Dog', 'Horse', 'Rat']]} 
>>> keys
['Cat', 'Dog', 'Horse', 'Rat']
>>> data = {'Value': [['Cat', 'Dog', 'Horse', 'Rat'], ['Dog', 'Horse', 'Rat']]} 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
                    Value
0  [Cat, Dog, Horse, Rat]
1       [Dog, Horse, Rat]
>>> df.Value.apply(lambda x: dict((key,"Yes") if key in x else (key,"No") for key in keys))
0    {'Rat': 'Yes', 'Cat': 'Yes', 'Dog': 'Yes', 'Ho...
1    {'Rat': 'Yes', 'Cat': 'No', 'Dog': 'Yes', 'Hor...
Name: Value, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

With `set` object and simple condition:

```
In [386]: names = set(s for lst in df['Value'].values for s in lst)

In [387]: df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(lambda row: {n: 'Yes' if n in row else 'No' for n in names})

In [388]: df
Out[388]: 
   Index                                              Value
0      0  {'Cat': 'Yes', 'Rat': 'Yes', 'Horse': 'No', 'D...
1      1  {'Cat': 'Yes', 'Rat': 'No', 'Horse': 'Yes', 'D...
2      2  {'Cat': 'Yes', 'Rat': 'Yes', 'Horse': 'Yes', '...
3      3  {'Cat': 'Yes', 'Rat': 'Yes', 'Horse': 'Yes', '...
4      4  {'Cat': 'No', 'Rat': 'Yes', 'Horse': 'Yes', 'D...
```